# Not Able to view layout preview in my Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have imported a project into Eclipse But I am not able to view layout preview in Android studio. Please take a look at the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: You android api is showing null, can you try selecting a proper api

Answer (score 0):

Try changing APIs in API drop down as shown in image, I was experiencing a same issue, so i changed API 23 to API 22 , now it is ok .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFITF.png)